Setting up a second monitor on the left side
I recently added a 2nd monitor to my existing Dell laptop (2nd monitor set on the left side of my laptop) running on Ubuntu 22.04. It works fine, but I am unable to find a setting that will allow my mouse pointer to leave the main screen of my laptop from the left side of the screen and reappear on the right side of the left monitor. I can only leave the main screen from the right side of it with the mouse reappearing on the left side of the left monitor.
Is that something that can be fixed, or do I have to live with it that way?
2nd monitor arrangement:


Go to Settings -> System settings -> Display and Monitor and move your second monitor to the left position of your main display/laptop monitor. Should be as easy as that.

Start 'Display Configuration' and you will see a visual representation of your two displays. Move them so that they are in the reverse order and click Apply.
Alternately, just swap the two physical displays or their cords. =)

OMG that was so simple, never taught of trying to moving them around on that setting screen , thanks
